# How to detect VSCode panel visibility from the extension code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to create an extension to toggle all the currently visible panels by a single shortcut. So something like the command "Hide/show All Tool Windows" from JetBrains IDEs, which I think is still missing in VS Code.

VS Code can have up to 3 panels visible:

- Sidebar (the left-side panel)
- Panel (the bottom panel)
- AuxiliaryBar (the new right-side panel)

For that purpose, I need to detect the current state of all the panels from the extension code, so I can toggle only the panel(s) which are currently visible.

But alas I can't find it anywhere in the documentation. This page (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts) contains several variables like `sideBarVisible`, but I really don't get how to access those context variables from the vscode namespace which you can access from the extension.

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
```

So, is there a way how to detect if the panel is open or closed from the extension code?

Comment: Can't you just run the commands `workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility`, `workbench.action.togglePanel` and `workbench.action.toggleAuxiliaryBar`?

Comment: If one is open and the others are closed what do you want to do?  Open them all or close them all?

Comment: @Mark If one panel is open and the others are closed, then I want to toggle only the one panel. If all are open, I want to toggle them all. Basically I would like to toggle (open/close) the panels that are currently open, like it works in JetBrains.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to know whether they are open or closed? Can't you just toggle them all?

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility')
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.togglePanel')
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.toggleAuxiliaryBar')
```

Comment: Without knowing the current state of panels, I can't cover all use-cases. Imagine to have 2 panels open and 1 panel closed, then running only these toggle commands would make 2 panels to close but 1 panel to open. So, I need to detect and remember which panels are open, so I can toggle only those by the shortcut. At least, it works this way in the JetBrains IDEs.