# VSCode Extension API to evaluate when-clauses

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Ultimately, I'd like to create a VSCode extension with a command to hide sidebars and panel and another one to recover them with another command. The idea is to have a quick keybind to maximize / unmaximize editor on smaller screens.

Calling a command to hide components is easy, but I also need to be able to check whether any of the three components (two sidebars + panel) are hidden. It is possible to add a `when` clause to a keybinding, or to register a context key for your own extension.

I'm looking for a way to evaluate when clauses programmatically inside my extension or just manually inspect context values properties of bars/panel. I'd expect something like:

```
vscode.commands.evaluateWhenClause("sideBarVisible")
```

or

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('getContext', 'sideBarVisible')
```

Is it possible in VS Code extension API?

I guess this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71541244/2912797), but a bit more generic.

Comment: There must be something similar, but I think you need to dig into VS Code source code.

Comment: @LexLi, I already found code that can access the contexts from the Inspect Context Keys utility, but it's not part of VS Code API, so I don't know how to use it in an extension and I don't know whether this is allowed or even possible.

Comment: I think an old thread (the last portion) and its linked threads, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10471 already covered enough background. The "get context" API was denied, so you cannot get something like that right now.